# How to check if IIS use sticky session?

Tags: session, iis

I'm developing applications on farm of IIS servers. I need to know if those IIS servers use sticky session to handle successive request from one client.

How to check if IIS server has turned on sticky session?

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide some additional details as to how your farm of IIS servers is load balanced?  There are several ways applications can be load balanced including [Windows Network Load Balancing (NLB)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732855%28WS.10%29.aspx), an IIS server running [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing), and of course hardware load balancers from companies such as Cisco, Citrix, Barracuda, and (my personal favorite) [F5](http://www.f5.com/products/big-ip/).

Sticky sessions (also referred to as persistence and server affinity), is not going to be set directly in IIS on the individual servers in your farm, so there really isn't a way to tell if persistence is enabled by looking at the IIS configuration.  The load balancer is what maintains the relationship between the client and the specific node that should receive the traffic and if it should send returning traffic back to the same web server where it made the first initial request.  Persistence settings will be configured in your load balancing solution.  For specifics on how exactly you need to do that, you will need to refer to the documentation of whatever load balancer (either hardware or software) you are using.